# Get sequence of number by cumsum

Tags: r

how can I get the output with 1 3 6 10 15 20 20 20 these numbers by only using Cumulative Summaries rather than c()?
I know that > cumsum(1:5)
[1]  1  3  6 10 15

Comment: `pmin(20, cumsum(1:10))`?

Comment: @r2evans you should have posted as an answer as your timing is better

Comment: ... by three seconds :-)

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if I completely understand but maybe -

```
pmin(cumsum(1:8), 20)
#[1]  1  3  6 10 15 20 20 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the great answer by [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68622905/12158757), you can also use

```
> replace(u<-cumsum(1:8),u>=20,20)
[1]  1  3  6 10 15 20 20 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
v1 <- cumsum(1:8)
v1[v1 >=20] <- 20
```